# Flutter Custom Text Field

Tags: flutter, material-ui, textfield

I want to create a custom text field in flutter like shown in the picture. Outlined TextField border with label and icon in the middle of the border line.
Is there any way to create such TextField?

[image: custom text field]

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stack to achieve the UI

```
Stack(
       children: [
         TextFormField(
           ...apply the border here
         ),
         Positioned(
           left: 16.0,
           top: 5.0,
           child: Container(
             padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
             color: AppColors.whiteColor,
             child: Row(
               children: [
                 Image.asset(your_image),
                 Text("Name")
               ],
             ),
           ),
         ),
         
       ],
    );
```

Comment: Thank you.. Just created the TextField.. But positioned need to be top 0 and add margin to the TextField widget to center align properly..